# HSRP vs VRRP interface tracking

Tags: cisco, hsrp, vrrp

Was reading a Cisco presentation and there was that VRRP does not have a native interface tracking mechanism but it does have the ability to track objects. Such objects include also uplink statuses of  interfaces. Now I understand that HSRP has native interface tracking and object tracking which can include advanced interface tracking, not only line protocol. How does VRRP differs object tracking for interfaces differs from those employed by HSRP?

Comment: Why do people expect network engineers to do your homework?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean or think the difference in what you call "_native interface tracking_" and tracking an interface as an object. Object tracking really just adds to what you can track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object tracking for any service that uses enhanced object tracking is the same. HSRP, VRRP and GLBP all use enhanced object tracking in the same way.

The original HSRP tracking simply tracked the line protocol of an interface, which you can do with enhanced object tracking, but there are many more things you can do with enhanced object tracking. This subject is far too large to give you a complete tutorial on it, but Cisco maintains many documents regarding this, and all you need to do is search.